# Match any word but two in specific

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expresion to match any word ( `\w+` ) except true or false.

This is what I got so far is: `\w+\s*=\s*[^true|^false]\w+`

```
class Ntnf { 
 public static void main ( String ... args ) { 
  System.out.println( args[0].matches("\\w+\\s*=\\s*[^true|^false]\\w+") );
 }
}
```

But is not working for:

```
a = b
a = true
a = false
```

It matches always.

How can I match any word ( `\w+` ) except true or false?

**EDIT**

I'm trying to spot this pattern:

```
a = b
x = y
name = someothername
etc = xyz
x = truea
n = falsea
```

But avoid matching

```
a = true
etc = false
name = true
```

Comment: maybe you can split it into 2 patterns, one mataches WORD = WORD, another matches WORD = true|false, then `if ( MATCH1 && ! MATCH2 )`

Comment: Looks like that's what I'll end up doing... :( ...

Comment: You have the wrong syntax; `[^blah]` is a negated character class. It matches a single character that is anything but `b`, `l`, `a`, or `h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
^(?!(true|false)$)
```

- ^ - beginning of string
- ?! - negative lookahead
- $ - end of string

So it matches as long as the whole string isn't just "true" or "false".  Note that it can still start with one of those.

However, it may be more straightforward to use regular string comparisons.

EDIT:

The whole regex (without escaping) for your situation is:

```
^\w+\s*=\s*(?!(true|false)$)\w+$
```

It's the same idea, except that we're putting it in the equation form.

Comment: @OscarRyz here is an explanation about lookaheads: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Should the phrase "This is true" be matched? The requirements aren't clear on if it should be, which would pose a significant problem with this solution.

Comment: *"This is true"* should not match

Comment: Awesome! I knew there was a regexp solution for this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`[^true]` Is a [**character class**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html). It only matches **one character**. `[^true]` means: "Match this character only if it not one of `t`, `r`, `u` or `e`". This is not what you need, right?

Regex is not a good idea for this task. It will be quite complicated to do it in regex. Just use string comparison.

Comment: That's not what I thought it should be. Thanks for the comment. Let's wait for an answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets match a list of possible characters, or reject a list of possible characters (not necessarily in the order you specify), so [^true] is not the way to go.

When I'm trying not to match a certain word, I usually do the following:
`([^t]|t[^r]|tr[^u]|tru[^e])`